# How to use test selector plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using test selector plugin for testing my python tests.

The setting step is OK and I can get the properties from the property file.

But when I click on the button of "Build with Parameters" I get an error

> File does not exist OR Jenkins does not have permission for this file

I think the permission is access and the file exist, how to solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide more details like, what is the full path to the file?
What are the permissions on the directory where the file is located?
What are the permissions of the properties file?

Comment: the path of example.properties file is "E:\jenkins_workplace\xh_master\example.properties",and i can fetch properties from file. And now i just write 2 test which is test_1 and test_2 in the example.properties. i think i should get a tree of them. And sorry about that i can not understand "What are the permissions on the directory where the file is located?"

Comment: format and details

Comment: i just copy the example.properity file from [link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Tests+Selector+Plugin),and follow the tutorial, i think i should get a test tree but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'Properties File Path' make sure the path is specified like this (with slash, not backslash):

```
C:/yourdir/yourfile.properties
```

**and NOT**

```
C:\yourdir\yourfile.properties
```